# list of inline images to wrap

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have a series of 10 images (thumbnails) 90x45 px I'd like to be listed horizontally, which I managed to by using inline-flex, in two rows of 5.
Problem is that when resizing the window at a certain size (1024px-1180) the last image overlaps the right column.
I am using bootstrap 3.0 with a 3-5-4 setup.

I would like to use one row so that regardless of how many images they'd wrap in new row.

i.e.
this

```
<div>
img1-img2-img3-img4-img5-img6-img7-img8-img9-img10-img11...
</div>
```

would become

```
<div>
img1-img2-img3-img4-
img5-img6-img7-img8-
img9-img10-img11...
</div>
```

This is what I have now

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
content
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ul class="fz-thumbnails-ul">
            <li>
                <div class="fz-intro-link">
                <a class="fz-thumbnail-links fz-nav-link fz-first-link" href="#item-1a">
                <div class="fz-hover-slide">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image1.jpg" />
                </div>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image1.jpg" />
                </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="fz-intro-link">
                <a class="fz-thumbnail-links fz-nav-link" href="#item-2a">
                <div class="fz-hover-slide">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image2.jpg" />
                </div>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image2.jpg" />
                </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="fz-intro-link">
                <a class="fz-thumbnail-links fz-nav-link" href="#item-3a">
                <div class="fz-hover-slide">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image3.jpg" />
                </div>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image3.jpg" />
                </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="fz-intro-link">
                <a class="fz-thumbnail-links fz-nav-link" href="#item-4a">
                <div class="fz-hover-slide">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image4.jpg" />
                </div>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image4.jpg" />
                </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="fz-intro-link">
                <a class="fz-thumbnail-links fz-nav-link" href="#item-5a">
                <div class="fz-hover-slide">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image5.jpg" />
                </div>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image5.jpg" />
                </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="fz-intro-link">
                <a class="fz-thumbnail-links fz-nav-link" href="#item-6a">
                <div class="fz-hover-slide">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image6.jpg" />
                </div>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="image6.jpg" />
                </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    content
</div>
```

of course the list goes on with as many items as images.
The relevant (I think) css I have is this

```
.fz-thumbnails-ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 0;
}
.fz-thumbnails-ul > li {
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;
}
```

Thank you

*EDIT*
My solution thanks to LOTUSMS sample, changed the above css to this

```
.fz-thumbnails-ul  {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.fz-thumbnails-ul li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add a working code snippet with what we can work. The code listing above doesn't show the issue.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by working, shall I post the whole list?

Comment: I edited with the whole list, and columns.

Comment: This is what I mean, https://jsfiddle.net/jg3uwu6m/, and as you can see, that code doesn't show the issue you referring in your question. Please update that fiddle so it shows the issue, save it and post its link.

Comment: Can you mock it up in a simpler form? I built this codepen for you but since I'm not sure if this answers your question, I'd post it here instead. If it does, I'll move it to the answer so you can mark it, if it doesn't, then let me know where to go from there. http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/qbmopq

Comment: Thank you both. LOTUSMS your solution is basically what I need, I tried applying it to my scenario, but failed, obviously I am missing something. Please take a look here to see the actual page so you can suggest the changes needed: ttri.biz/fz_test/image-list/lamborghini.php

Comment: Got it. See the OP, changed the css moving the display from fz-thumbnails-ul to fz-thumbnails-ul li

Comment: @LOTUSMS If you want to put the answer I'll be glad to mark it, since your sample did lead me to the solution. Thank you

Comment: @keneso Thanks, I moved it to an answer. Now others can benefit should they stumble on your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some classes cleanup and CSS re-structure, your solution will work if you follow this as a guideline and modify accordingly:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 left">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="fz-intro-link">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.photosofireland.ie/phot/photos/thumbnails/Lough-Leane-Nov-opt-pano-II%20wmark_90x0.jpg" />
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.photosofireland.ie/phot/photos/thumbnails/Lough-Leane-Nov-opt-pano-II%20wmark_90x0.jpg" />
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.photosofireland.ie/phot/photos/thumbnails/Lough-Leane-Nov-opt-pano-II%20wmark_90x0.jpg" />
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.photosofireland.ie/phot/photos/thumbnails/Lough-Leane-Nov-opt-pano-II%20wmark_90x0.jpg" />
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.photosofireland.ie/phot/photos/thumbnails/Lough-Leane-Nov-opt-pano-II%20wmark_90x0.jpg" />
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.photosofireland.ie/phot/photos/thumbnails/Lough-Leane-Nov-opt-pano-II%20wmark_90x0.jpg" />
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.photosofireland.ie/phot/photos/thumbnails/Lough-Leane-Nov-opt-pano-II%20wmark_90x0.jpg" />
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.photosofireland.ie/phot/photos/thumbnails/Lough-Leane-Nov-opt-pano-II%20wmark_90x0.jpg" />
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.photosofireland.ie/phot/photos/thumbnails/Lough-Leane-Nov-opt-pano-II%20wmark_90x0.jpg" />
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.photosofireland.ie/phot/photos/thumbnails/Lough-Leane-Nov-opt-pano-II%20wmark_90x0.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 right">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fz-intro-link img {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 9px;
}
.left{
    background:green;
}
.center{
    background:blue;
}
.right{
    background:orange;
}
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/qbmopq)

:)

Comment: Tahnk you ;) - Darn I thought I could upvote, but it still tells me I need to get a higher reputation. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. :) You can still check it as answer I think. But it's cool. I'm glad I helped you out.

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that you need to click the check mark, now it's marked as answer.